# Android alarmmanager cancel and start not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have the following code to set an alarm when the main activity starts and cancel when logging out

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    // Schedule alarm
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null) {
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    }
}

private void logOut() {
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmIntent.cancel();
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);

    finish();
}
```

But when I log out, log back in, and enter the main activity the code `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` is never reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line will never be reached, because your `PendingIntent` that you are checking will always exist, because you are creating that `PendingIntent` two lines earlier. Since the `PendingIntent` exists, the `FLAG_NO_CREATE` call will still return it, and that will not equal `null`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your if statement evaluates to false. According to your code, you will have an instance of a PendingIntent with that request every time you hit the if block.